# Java spring thymeleaf Display Picture

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to display picture in page html with concat with source and name of picture in database
Example :

```
<tr th:each="e:${PageEtudiants.content}">
<td> <img class="img img-circle" width="50" height="50" `th:src="@{/Upload/(${e.photo})}"/></td>
</tr>`
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code

```
<img class="img img-circle" width="50" height="50" th:src="@{'/Upload/'+${e.photo()}}"/>
```